# Foto salva no Diretório não aparece no Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, visual-studio, imagem

Depois de muito penar, conseguir salvar a foto no diretório e  não no banco. Porém ela na aparece na minha pastinha lá no meu Solution Explorer, mais ao abrir a foto pelo windows explore ela aparece.

Por conta disso a foto não é exibida ao se editar o registro. Como deve proceder?

Codigo que salva a Foto:

```
int n = 0;
        Boolean valido = true;
        foreach (var item in ModelState.Values)
        {
            n++;
            if ((item.Value == null) && (n < 12))
            {
                valido = false;
            }
        }
        if (valido == true)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var pat = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(pat);

            frota.URLFoto = fileName;
            db.Frotas.Add(frota);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

HTML do razor:

```
@{ var foto = Model.URLFoto;
   var pat = Path.Combine("~/Fotos/", foto); }

<img src="@pat" width="172" height="92" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 172px; height: 92px;" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanto é normal quanto é ótimo que a foto não aparece no Solution Explorer, até porque os arquivos que aparecem no Solution Explorer são arquivos do projeto. Incorreto seria se fotos que não pertencem ao projeto aparecessem no projeto.

Agora, se a foto não aparece ao editar o registro, significa que o procedimento de carregar esta foto está incorreto. Edite sua pergunta, colocando o código de carregamento de imagem para que eu possa prover uma resposta mais direcionada e correta para o seu problema.

---

**EDIT**

Faltou `Server.MapPath` também na hora de carregar a foto:

```
@{ var foto = Model.URLFoto;
   var pat = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/"), foto); }

<img src="@pat" width="172" height="92" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 172px; height: 92px;" />
```

Comment: Nada ainda! A foto não aparece

Comment: @LuizFelipe Por favor, inspecione o HTML ao renderizar. O que é preenchido em `src`?

Comment: Eu já fiz isso. ele traz o caminho completo da imagem. e é um caminho valido!

Comment: @LuizFelipe Pode atualizar sua pergunta com o que aparece no HTML?

Comment: Ah, deixa pra lá. vou salvar as fotos no banco mesmo!

Comment: Não entendi esse deixa pra lá. Programar é isso, precisa de paciência, determinação e lógica. Insista mais, dê mais detalhe, edite a pergunta com mais riqueza de detalhes. Desculpe-me, na boa, se desistir sempre diante da primeira dificuldade, amigo, não vais longe. Desejo-lhes sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Para gravar uma imagem no banco de dados, primeiro defina a tabela que receberá os dados, sugiro uma tabela somente com a imagem (o que ficará mais prático quando não carregar a imagem), e um ou mais campos para indicar a quem pertence.

O campo que receberá a imagem deve ser do tipo byte para MSSQL, não sei qual o seu BD então terá que pesquisar um pouco, no local de carregar a foto, transforme em bytes e envie para o banco, salvando com os dados complementares.

Transformando arquivo em byte

```
byte[] arquivoByte = new byte[FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Length+1];
FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(arquivoByte,0,arquivoByte.Length);
```